# What Scriptures are used to justify the belief that Christians of Denominations other than a specific one will be rejected by God?

Tags: biblical-basis, denomination-survey, worship

In my studies of the Bible I have never found times when God has rejected the worship of anyone who worshipped him in sincerity.

The only restrictions to worship other than worshipping in holiness as far as I have been able to find is in:

> Again I say unto you, That if two of you shall agree on earth as touching any thing that they shall ask, it shall be done for them of my Father which is in heaven. For where two or three are gathered together in my name, there am I in the midst of them. (Matthew 18:19-20, KJV)

And David in Psalms decreed:

> Who shall ascend into the hill of the Lord? or who shall stand in his holy place? He that hath clean hands, and a pure heart; who hath not lifted up his soul unto vanity, nor sworn deceitfully.  He shall receive the blessing from the Lord, and righteousness from the God of his salvation. This [is] the generation of them that seek him, that seek thy face, O Jacob. Selah. (Psalms 24:3-6, KJV)
>
> Give unto the Lord the glory due unto his name; worship the Lord in the beauty of holiness. (Psalms 29:2, KJV)

And in Hosea it says:

> For I desired mercy, and not sacrifice; and the knowledge of God more than burnt offerings. (Hosea 6:6, KJV)

As far as I am able to determine God  does not seem to be concerned except that we humbly worship him in righteousness.

So for those who do believe that God only accepts a single denomination, what scriptural passages do they use to back it up?

Comment: The issue is not whether or not our names are written on a particular denomination's membership roles, but whether or not it is written in the book of life.

Comment: Sincerity if you're wrong is deadly. So sure, humility and sincerity are essential, but so is truth.

Comment: @Narnian I whole heartedly agree! however that is not my question, having been assaulted by some Denominations which appear to believe that theirs is the only Denomination which will inhabit Heaven, always want to read me a particular verse from the Bible, but it is my experience that one verse alone usually gives one a slanted view and only in relation to other Scriptures can full meaning be extracted. I wish to research their Scriptures for myself, thus I ask what scriptures are used in justification of their assertions.

Comment: @Bye Could you narrow it down to a particular denomination that believes this?  The verses will vary accordingly.

Comment: @curiousdannii You appear to be misreading my question, It is not whether they are right or wrong in their belief that I am asking, it is for the Scriptures they use so that I can research them for myself. I do not question anyone's devotion to God or whether they are right or wrong that is not for me to judge, it is for Jesus to judge. That does not mean that I cannot be curious about their Interpretation of Scriptures. I have been wrong once before in my 76 years so I am curious.

Comment: @Narnian I can but my interest is as much in do they all use the same Scriptures as it is the specific Scriptures. and at the risk of this being rejected as a list question I prefer to ask one question rather than a dozen or so. Using the same Scriptures would deny specificity of any particular Denomination.

Comment: I'm just wary of sincerity language because of those who like to say that sincere Muslims will be accepted by god.

Comment: @curiousdannii That is a good thing, but at the same time we need to remember Matthew 15:8  This people draweth nigh unto me with their mouth, and honoureth me with their lips; but their heart is far from me. The problem you site isnot in the sincerity of worship it is in the one who is worshipped.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on whom you ask.

Answer (score 3):

The first scripture that occurs to me in this connection is Galatians 1:8, where St. Paul writes: "But though we, or an angel from heaven, preach a gospel to you besides that which we have preached to you, let him be anathema."

Answer (score 3):

(LDS view)

## “One Lord, One Faith, One Baptism”

Mormons are strong proponents of the claim that *only one* denomination of Christianity is recognized by God, and that *all* other denominations:

> "...teach for doctrines the commandments of men, having a form of
>   godliness, but they deny the power thereof." ([Joseph Smith History 1:19](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/js-h/1.19?lang=eng#18))

One scripture that they use to support this is [Ephesians 4:5](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/eph/4.5?lang=eng)

> "One Lord, one faith, one baptism,"

There is only one true God, so there can only be one true Church.

An excellent explanation of this scripture is given in [Chapter 44](https://www.lds.org/manual/new-testament-student-manual/ephesians/chapter-44-ephesians?lang=eng) of the New Testament Student Manual:

---

The word “one” appears seven times in [Ephesians 4:4–6](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/eph/4.4-6?lang=eng#3). Oneness and unity are important themes in Ephesians and in Paul’s other writings. Paul constantly preached about unity and prayed for unity among Church members (see [Romans 12:5;](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/rom/12.5?lang=eng#4) [1 Corinthians 1:10;](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-cor/1.10?lang=eng#9) [2 Corinthians 13:11](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/2-cor/13.11?lang=eng#10)). In modern times, the Lord revealed to Joseph Smith that unity is a key law of the celestial kingdom (see [D&C 105:3–5](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/105.3-5?lang=eng#2)). There is only one true Lord, one true faith, one true baptism, and one true Father of all.

**Elder Delbert L. Stapley** (1896–1978) of the Quorum of the Twelve Apostles spoke of the critical role Apostles played in maintaining unity and pure doctrine:

> “After Jesus put his apostles in charge of the Church anciently, they
>   preached the same unity of doctrine and practiced the same ordinances
>   which Jesus had given them. …
>
> “… As long as they remained on the earth, functioning under the
>   authority Jesus gave them, unity of doctrine and uniformity of the
>   ordinances prevailed. The gospel message, which they were commanded to
>   take to all the world, was the same to everyone everywhere. People
>   were not taught different gospels and then given a choice. There was
>   only one plan for all.
>
> “Because of the universality of these requirements for salvation, the
>   apostle Paul wrote: ‘There is … one Lord, one faith, one baptism.’
>   ([Eph. 4:4–5.](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/eph/4.4-5?lang=eng#3)) …
>
> “**One church, one authorized ministry, one orthodox gospel doctrine,
>   and one Holy Ghost characterized the church of Jesus Christ in His
>   time. ‘For God is not the author of confusion, but of peace, as in all
>   churches of the saints.’** ([1 Cor. 14:33](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-cor/14.33?lang=eng#32).) Thus God’s revelation to
>   leaders of the Church of Jesus Christ was reasonable, consistent, and
>   unified.
>
> “It was only after the death of Christ’s apostles that revelation
>   ceased. The pure doctrines Christ taught became diluted with the
>   philosophy of the world, and profane innovations appeared in the
>   ordinances of the church. Eventually, that which had once been clear
>   and understandable became mythical and confusing” ([“What Constitutes
>   the True Church,”](https://www.lds.org/ensign/1977/05/what-constitutes-the-true-church.p1?lang=eng) Ensign, May 1977, 22).

Answer (score 3):

> 21 “Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but only the one who does the will of my Father who is in heaven. 22 Many will say to me on that day, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in your name and in your name drive out demons and in your name perform many miracles?’ 23 Then I will tell them plainly, ‘I never knew you. Away from me, you evildoers!’” ([Matthew 7:21-23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%207%3A21-23&version=NIV), NIV)

A person who claims Jesus as their Lord (ie a Christian) must do the will of Jesus' Father, Almighty God. Even if they do all sorts of great things, if they don't do what the Father says to do, they will be rejected.

Some denominations do certain things based on what they interpret as God's will, so they may believe that other denominations not doing those God-willed things would be rejected, according to this verse.

Comment: Welcome Scott! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).